# macOS: How do you detect a plus sign keypress regardless of keyboard layout?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want my app to make the text bigger when user presses `COMMAND` + `+`. So I write:

```
if event.charactersIgnoringModifiers == "=" { ... }
```

But in Germany, for example, the equals sign is on a different key than the plus sign. I'm not familiar with how many of the world's keyboards work that way.

Do I need to go look at all of the hundreds of different keyboard layouts and find the lowercase character of the plus sign key for all of them, and write a class that detects user's language and returns that character?

Comment: This is hard because you're going about it in the "wrong" way. There are APIs for integrating and handling keyboard shortcuts; in AppKit that's `keyEquivalent` (for [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1524690-performkeyequivalent?language=objc)).If you use the proper technique you get a lot of functionality for free.

Comment: Did you check what the value of `event.charactersIgnoringModifiers` is when you type Command-`+` on your and foreign keyboards (= foreign input methods)?

Comment: Is there a "Bigger" menu item? In the Xcode template it's in the Format menu.

Answer (score -2):

Command-plus is always a tricky one. I think for most cases it should be sufficient to check for three cases:

1. The NSEvent's `characters` property. You should check this in case the keyboard has a specific command character plane that explicitly puts '+' in a special position.
2. As you mentioned, you can check the `charactersIgnoringModifiers` property in case that catches a plane in the layout with '+' on that key.
3. Starting in macOS 10.15 you can also use the `-charactersByApplyingModifiers:` method to what the character *would be* if a certain modifier were pressed. In this case you can pass in NSEventModifierFlagShift to see if the shift plane gives you a '+'.

I believe that should cover 99.9% of the cases. The remaining cases would be people who have written their own custom keyboard layouts where the '+' key is not on any key in the main plane, the command plane, or the shift plane. But if they're typing on such a layout they have only themselves to blame for not being able to command-plus in your app. :)

(As a reminder, if your deployment target is earlier than macOS 10.15, you can still get this behavior for users on 10.15+ by wrapping the relevant code inside `if (@available(macOS 10.15, *)) { ... }`.)